# TSQL split column between first and second occurence of delimiter from left

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that looks like this

```
| col1 | 
| -------- | 
| 12345 987456 item thing    | 
| 56455 456842 word word word   | 
| 56845 456584 word word   |
```

I am looking to select the number between the first and the second occurrence of the space.
I.e

```
| new-col1 | 
| -------- | 
| 987456    | 
| 456842  | 
| 456584  |
```

As reflected in my data the amount of delimiters(space) and length varies so I cannot use `PARSENAME()`.

I tried to use `SPLIT_STRING` as well but it is not recognised even though my specs should allow for it

***Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU23) (KB5000685) - 14.0.3381.3 (X64)
Compatibilty 140***

Comment: Why you store multipe information in the same field at all? Clean your data before you insert it, not everytime you take it out.

Comment: While I agree - I am not in a position to change this.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1 ,CHARINDEX(' ',Col1,1)+1, CHARINDEX(' ',Col1,CHARINDEX(' ',Col1,1)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Col1,1)-1) NewCol1
FROM #TAB